# c malloc() - do I need to allocate space for the null terminator

Tags: c, string, malloc, null-terminated

I have a snippet of code below that appends the text `_dut1_serial_log.txt` to a supplied filename. The supplied filename is a variable in the struct pointed to by `targetP`.

The text `_dut1_serial_log.txt` is 20 chars long. My question is do I need the `+1` when I call malloc for the null terminator?

```
char *filename_ending = "_dut1_serial_log.txt";
    char *filename_with_extension;
    prv_instance_t *targetP = threadParams->targetP;

    /*append filename ending "_dut1_serial_log.txt" to filename supplied*/
    filename_with_extension = malloc(strlen(targetP->output_filename)+1+20);
    strcpy(filename_with_extension, targetP->output_filename); /* copy name into the new var */
    strcat(filename_with_extension, filename_ending); /* add the extension */
```

Comment: What makes you think you don't need to allocate space for the NUL terminator?

Comment: If you don't allocate memory for it, you are not allowed to store it. Who else could be responsible for allocating that extra memory?

Comment: This is very bad: `filename_with_extension = malloc(strlen(targetP->output_filename)+1+20);`. What happens if you change to filename from `"_dut1_serial_log.txt"` to `"mylongfilename_whatever.txt"`? Write `malloc(strlen(targetP->output_filename) + strlen(filename_ending) + 1);`. Or better : `char filename_ending[] = "_dut1_serial_log.txt";` and `malloc(strlen(targetP->output_filename) + sizeof(filename_ending));`

Comment: @MichaelWalz thank you for your suggestion. many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `strcpy` and `strcat` *will* copy the NUL-terminator from the source string to the destination buffer.

You do need to reserve space for that terminator in the destination buffer therefore.

To avoid any doubt, `"_dut1_serial_log.txt"` is a `const char[21]` type.

Comment: "To avoid any doubt, "_dut1_serial_log.txt" is a const char[21] type.", not strictly conforming but whatever.